# How to monitor the temperature of a switch?

Tags: switch, physical-environment

Is there any application that give me the temperature of each switches on my network?

Comment: Tell us what kind of switches you've got, we might be able to give you the SNMP OID to poll to get the value you're looking for...

Comment: we got 3com and SMC

Answer (score 3):

Some high end switches include temperature sensors. These can usually be queried through SNMP, google your switch models for how to do this.

Failing that, you'll have to put external temperature sensors in the cabinets with them. It really just depends on the kit you have.

Answer (score 1):

Most switches (Juniper, Cisco, Foundry, HP etc) will expose a wide range of metrics via SNMP.  On Linux/Unix, the simplest tool for extracting this informtion is snmpwalk.

In order to do this, you need to know the MIB (Management Information Base) relevant to your switch and the OID (Object Identifier) of the metric you want.

For example, you might establish the OID of the sensor you need is 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91.1.1.1.1.4.  In which case, assuming the IP of the switch is 10.2.2.1, you would type:

`# snmpwalk -c public 10.2.2.1 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.91.1.1.1.1.4`

This will give you a number of values that you can interpret or graph.  Monitoring software such as (amongst many) Cacti or Zabbix typically provides SNMP capabilities which enables you to carry out trend analysis and fault detection based on this information.

Answer (score 0):

It depends your switch provides this feature, see the device documentation.
But I don't understand why do you need switch temperature, you think it's overheating?

Comment: This sounds like a cheap way to do widespread environmental monitoring to me.  Which is cool (hopefully (: ).

Comment: yes, we don't have server room and some of our rack doesn't have fan, I just want to know the status

Answer (score 0):

If the switches have temperature sensors then they'll be monitorable via the manufacturers management software and also if they make their MIB available then by any other SNMP management system like Nagios/Munin etc.